# how to use Netinfo in if statement in React Native Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-community-netinfo

i need to use the NetInfo.isConnected in a variable to send to my if statement, but all examples i see in internet are the same, just console.log the value, never put inside a variable

```js
function verifyConnection() {
  let isConnected;
  NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => {
    isConnected = state.isConnected;
  });
  return isConnected;
}
```

always return undefined, but if a put into a variable like this

```
let isConnected = NetInfo.fetch().then((state) => {state.isConnected});
```

return : LOG  {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}

how to use netinfo inside a if statemente to test my connection status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async` and `await` to wait a promise to resolve

```
async function verifyConnection() {
  return (await NetInfo.fetch()).isConnected;
}
```

or `useNetInfo` hook when rendering components.

```
const Component = () => {
  const netInfo = useNetInfo();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected?.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```